# javascript check time and display message

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

How do you retrieve the hours and minutes of `Date` object and then display a message? If the time is between 9pm and 12am I want to display "We are closed", otherwise I want to display "We are open".

```
<script language="javascript"> 
<!-- 
    today = new Date();
    document.write('<BR>We are Open');
//--> 
</script>
```

Comment: I would use a setTimeout for displaying and removing the message.

Comment: Which has as an effect that if you visit the site before 9pm and you stay until 9pm, it will popup still @9pm.

Answer (score 2):

`today` is a `Date`, so you can use its functions. In your case, use `today.getHours()` and check whether it's `>= 12` and `< 21` to show the opened message. The closed message can appear in an `else`.

Note that this uses the client's time, so if you're using this on a web page worldwide, then you might be opened in Europe but at the same time closed in the US.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got the "time logic" correct (check the if statement), but this should be what you are looking for.

```
var objDate = new Date();
var hours = objDate.getHours();
if(hours >= 12 && hours <= 21){
    document.write('We Are Closed');
}
else{
    document.write('We are Open');
}
```

Comment: thx for answer hmm it shows we are closed but if i change to <= -21) it shows we are open

Answer (score 1):

You can get Minutes And Hours From Date Using Following:

```
var d = new Date();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var h = d.getHours();
```

Compare your var h using following condition and get the desired result:

```
if(h>= 12 && h<= 21)
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for downvote for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i usually use this kind of solution, which i'm posting just for knowledge (pimvdb's answer is more clear indeed)

```
var d = new Date();
var currtime = d.getHours() * 100 + d.getMinutes();

// now your currtime looks like 530 if it's 5.30am, or 1730 if it's 5.30 pm
// you can just do a simple comparison between ints

if (currtime > 2000 and currtime < 800){
    // closed between 20:00 (8 pm) and 8:00 (8 am) as an example
    alert("We are closed");
}
```

you basically convert your time to an integer, making comparison easier (thus not so much readable and mantainable)